# How do variables work in mod ReWrite? Example included

Tags: apache

Can anybody explain how this is working?

```
RewriteRule ^update_my_account/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/?$      /index.php?page_id=$1&updated=$2 [L]
```

What part of the URL is $1 and $2 determined by?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$1 means first group anything matched by first ([0-9]+) in your rewrite regex and $2 is second ([0-9]+).

Comment: Thanks for that, can you explain to me what the /?$ means and what effect it is having on the above please? It comes just after the second group

Comment: $ It means end of string. and ? means 0 or 1. It means your url can end with /. update_my_account/123/123/ and update_my_account/123/123 will both match to above regex.

Comment: So if I have this in as a rule and link to "/update_my_account/30/1" should it redirect to /index.php?page_id=30&updated=1

Comment: Yes. This is internal rewrite not a redirect. To do a redirect you need add 301 as flag. like [301,L] instead of current [L].

Comment: Does an internal rewrite do the same thing, but keep the original URL in the address bar? Or do they bahave differently?

Answer (score 1):

`$1` contains whatever is matched by the first expression inside brackets `([0-9]+)`, and `$2` contains whatever is matched by the second `([0-9]+)`.